# How to check if one number is higher than other by value of 3?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How to check if NUM1 is higher than NUM2 by value of 3 and vice versa? in C# for Unity5

But NUM1 & NUM2 will increase value further the game goes.

(than do something)

example:

**Num 1:** 4,
**Num 2:** 7
= True
(than do something)

but in some minutes it might be

**NUM 1:** 5,
**NUM 2:** 7
= false
(than do something)

I have just basic IF statement but that works only for one value of NUM1 and NUM2, but if it changes I would need 100 of if statements for my project.

Comment: `Math.abs(NUM2-NUM1) > 3`

Comment: So you're asking how to find the difference between two numbers?

Comment: there is a lot of info missing: Do you want exact that difference or can it be more? what exactly is changing? the Num1, Num2 I guess but also the difference threshold? In general I would extend Heretic Monkey's comment to `if(Mathf.Abs(NUM1 - NUM2) > THRESHOLD) { ... } else { ... }` then all three values can be changed dynamically

Answer (score 5):

```cs
bool greaterByComparer(float num1, float num2, int comparer)
{
    return Math.abs(num2 - num1) == comparer;
}
```

Comment: 1. only if OP wants an exact difference of `3` , 2. OP: `and vice versa` -> @HereticMonkey 's comment is actually closer

Comment: I didn't see the or vice versa part, sorry.  I also did't think of other number types such.   I saw the op used ints in the question so I assumed that's all they needed.  Thanks for the feedback